# Why does the function pointer get overwritten even though is declared before the vulnerable buffer?

Tags: c, linux, assembly, x86

I am working on [io-wargames](http://io.smashthestack.org:84/) for fun right now, level3:

I do understand why there is a stack-overflow in this code `(strlen(argv[1])`), but what I don't understand is why it overflows the function pointer `functionpointer`.

`functionpointer` is declared before `char buffer[50];` on the stack so How comes it overwrites it ???

Here is the main vulnerable code:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp)
{
        void (*functionpointer)(void) = bad;
        char buffer[50];

        if(argc != 2 || strlen(argv[1]) < 4)
                return 0;

        memcpy(buffer, argv[1], strlen(argv[1]));
        memset(buffer, 0, strlen(argv[1]) - 4);

        printf("This is exciting we're going to %p\n", functionpointer);
        functionpointer();

        return 0;
}
```

Here is the shell exploits the stackoverflow:

```
level3@io:~$ /levels/level03 11111111
This is exciting we're going to 0x80484a4
I'm so sorry, you're at 0x80484a4 and you want to be at 0x8048474
level3@io:~$ /levels/level03 111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
This is exciting we're going to 0x31313100
Segmentation fault
```

---

Here is the `objump -d` of the executable:

```
080484c8 <main>:
 80484c8:       55                      push   %ebp
 80484c9:       89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 80484cb:       83 ec 78                sub    $0x78,%esp
 80484ce:       83 e4 f0                and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
 80484d1:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
 80484d6:       29 c4                   sub    %eax,%esp
 80484d8:       c7 45 f4 a4 84 04 08    movl   $0x80484a4,-0xc(%ebp)
 80484df:       83 7d 08 02             cmpl   $0x2,0x8(%ebp)
 80484e3:       75 17                   jne    80484fc <main+0x34>
 80484e5:       8b 45 0c                mov    0xc(%ebp),%eax
 80484e8:       83 c0 04                add    $0x4,%eax
 80484eb:       8b 00                   mov    (%eax),%eax
 80484ed:       89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp)
 80484f0:       e8 a7 fe ff ff          call   804839c <strlen@plt>
 80484f5:       83 f8 03                cmp    $0x3,%eax
 80484f8:       76 02                   jbe    80484fc <main+0x34>
 80484fa:       eb 09                   jmp    8048505 <main+0x3d>
 80484fc:       c7 45 a4 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x5c(%ebp)
 8048503:       eb 74                   jmp    8048579 <main+0xb1>
 8048505:       8b 45 0c                mov    0xc(%ebp),%eax
 8048508:       83 c0 04                add    $0x4,%eax
 804850b:       8b 00                   mov    (%eax),%eax
 804850d:       89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp)
 8048510:       e8 87 fe ff ff          call   804839c <strlen@plt>
 8048515:       89 44 24 08             mov    %eax,0x8(%esp)
 8048519:       8b 45 0c                mov    0xc(%ebp),%eax
 804851c:       83 c0 04                add    $0x4,%eax
 804851f:       8b 00                   mov    (%eax),%eax
 8048521:       89 44 24 04             mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
 8048525:       8d 45 a8                lea    -0x58(%ebp),%eax
 8048528:       89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp)
 804852b:       e8 5c fe ff ff          call   804838c <memcpy@plt>
 8048530:       8b 45 0c                mov    0xc(%ebp),%eax
 8048533:       83 c0 04                add    $0x4,%eax
 8048536:       8b 00                   mov    (%eax),%eax
 8048538:       89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp)
 804853b:       e8 5c fe ff ff          call   804839c <strlen@plt>
 8048540:       83 e8 04                sub    $0x4,%eax
 8048543:       89 44 24 08             mov    %eax,0x8(%esp)
 8048547:       c7 44 24 04 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,0x4(%esp)
 804854e:       00 
 804854f:       8d 45 a8                lea    -0x58(%ebp),%eax
 8048552:       89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp)
 8048555:       e8 02 fe ff ff          call   804835c <memset@plt>
 804855a:       8b 45 f4                mov    -0xc(%ebp),%eax
 804855d:       89 44 24 04             mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
 8048561:       c7 04 24 c0 86 04 08    movl   $0x80486c0,(%esp)
 8048568:       e8 3f fe ff ff          call   80483ac <printf@plt>
 804856d:       8b 45 f4                mov    -0xc(%ebp),%eax
 8048570:       ff d0                   call   *%eax
 8048572:       c7 45 a4 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x5c(%ebp)
 8048579:       8b 45 a4                mov    -0x5c(%ebp),%eax
 804857c:       c9                      leave  
 804857d:       c3                      ret    
 804857e:       90                      nop
 804857f:       90                      nop
```

---

I see that the complier reserved in the main's prolog function frame `0x78` bytes for the local main function variables.

Comment: this is a major spoiler for people playing the game, could you consider removing the actual exploit and adding spoiler tags where appropriate ?

Comment: @0xea I removed the explicit exploit. thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The compiler did put the function pointer after the buffer.

In the disassembly, check the `memcpy` call:

```
8048525:  lea    -0x58(%ebp),%eax
8048528:  mov    %eax,(%esp)
804852b:  call   804838c <memcpy@plt>
```

The first argument to `memcpy` (the buffer's address) is at `[esp+0]` and you can see that the value of `ebp-0x58` is being put there.

Next is the function call at the end of the function:

```
804856d:  mov    -0xc(%ebp),%eax
8048570:  call   *%eax
```

You can see that the address being jumped to is loaded from `[ebp-0xc]` which is 0x4c (76) bytes after the beginning of the character buffer.

Here's a stack layout from IDA which will hopefully make things clearer:

```
-00000058 buffer          db 76 dup(?)
-0000000C functionpointer dd ?
-00000008 var_8           dd ?
-00000004 var_4           dd ?
+00000000  s              db 4 dup(?)
+00000004  r              db 4 dup(?)
+00000008 argc            dd ?
+0000000C argv            dd ?
```

Offsets in the leftmost column are ebp-relative. Memory addresses increase downwards, so it's obvious that writing too much data into `buffer` will overwrite the function pointer (and then the return address).

MSVC actually uses a mitigation against such attack - it [reorders character buffers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc337897.aspx) to be placed after all other variables:

[image]

Comment: How IDA came with the `functionpointer` and `buffer` in its output ?

Comment: @0x90: I renamed them, obviously :) Though it might happen automatically if DWARF info is present (since 6.4).

Answer (score 11):

> functionpointer is declared before char buffer[50]; on the stack so How comes it overwrites it ???

The order of objects in the stack is implementation defined. C does not mention any stack and the direction of the stack growing is also implementation-defined (usually it grows downwards but in some systems it grows upwards).

In your case `functionpointer` is probably put first and then `buffer`. As in your system the stack grows downards, this allow you to overwrite `functionpointer` when overflowing `buffer`.

Answer (score 4):

> Why does the function pointer get overwritten even though is declared before the vulnerable buffer?

In the vulnerable code the order of declaration is:

```
void (*functionpointer)(void) = bad;  
char buffer[50];
```

The assembly code shows us that the **function pointer** variable is located at `ebp-0xc` and the **buffer** at `ebp-0x58`.

This proves that the **stack is growing downwards**(to lower addresses) in this system as the **buffer** is placed at a lower address than the **function pointer** variable.

Another proof that the stack is growing downwards in this system is the below instruction which allocates the required space by substracting `esp`:

```
80484cb:       83 ec 78                sub    $0x78,%esp
```

Now `memcpy` copies `num` bytes starting from the byte located at `ebp-0x58` and then it continues by incrementing.

Adding `1` to `ebp-0x58` makes it `ebp-0x57`, so if `num` is long enough, `memcpy` will overwrite the **function pointer** located at `ebp-0xc`.

`ebp` holds an address, lets say `0x00400000`, so `ebp-0x58` is the address `0x003FFFA8` incrementing from that address you will eventually reach `ebp-0xc(0x003FFFF4)`.

```
0x003FFFA8     buffer
...
0x003FFFF4     function pointer
0x003FFFF8     
0x003FFFFC    
0x00400000     saved ebp
0x00400004     saved return address
```